# T-SQL error with subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help with a T-SQL select statement. It is for SQL Server 2014

I have 3 tables.

- Table 1 (`Courses`) has 2 columns that I need to query on - `AllowReEnrollment` and `ReEnrollAutomatically`
- Table 2 (`CourseEnrollments`) has a `CourseId` column that is the foreign key to the `Id` of the `Courses` table. `Courses` can have multiple enrollments.
- Table 3 (`Jobs`) has a column called `Arguments` which holds Json data with one of the values being `EnrollmentId` `{"EnrollmentId":{ENROLLMENT_ID_GUID}}` which is the `Id` from the `CourseEnrollments` table

I need to check the Jobs table to find out if there are any jobs scheduled for a `CourseEnrollment` where its `Course` has had the `AllowReEnroll` flag turned off but the `ReEnrollAutomatically` flag is on.

This is what I have been trying

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Jobs
WHERE
    Arguments LIKE '%' + (
        SELECT
            CONVERT( nvarchar(50), Id )
        FROM
            CourseEnrollments
        WHERE
            CourseId IN (
                SELECT
                    Id
                FROM
                    Courses
                WHERE
                    AllowReEnroll = 0
                    AND
                    ReEnrollAutomatically = 1
            )
    ) +'%'
```

I can query the `CourseEnrollments` table to get all of the ids of `CourseEnrollments` where the Course's flags are set accordingly with

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CourseEnrollments
WHERE
    CourseId IN (
        SELECT
            Id
        FROM
            Courses
        WHERE
            AllowReEnroll = 0
            AND
            ReEnrollAutomatically = 1
    )
```

but when I try to use that as a subquery I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

Not being a dba I have spent the day trying to figure this out. How do I write this query?

Answer (score 3):

Use `EXISTS/Join` to do this

Using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Jobs j
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   CourseEnrollments c
               WHERE  c.CourseId IN (SELECT Id
                                     FROM   Courses
                                     WHERE  AllowReEnroll = 0
                                            AND ReEnrollAutomatically = 1)
                      AND j.Arguments LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), c.Id) + '%')
```

Using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT j.*
FROM   Jobs j
       JOIN CourseEnrollments c
         ON j.Arguments LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), c.Id) + '%'
WHERE  c.CourseId IN (SELECT Id
                      FROM   Courses
                      WHERE  AllowReEnroll = 0
                             AND ReEnrollAutomatically = 1)
```